# How can I cursor to highlight it in some cases working on phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

In  PhpStorm 2021.1.4 I periodically lose focus/cursor and have difficulties in finding it.
If there is a way to highlight it in some cases, say I return focus from other application to  PhpStorm
or making operations with current point moving, like ztrl+z ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As some kind of workaround you may enable the "Block caret" in "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance", it is definitely more visible.

Comment: I suppose option "Use Block caret" must be on ? Also I see option "Caret Blinking (ms)" with 500 as default value. Has it something for this issue?

Comment: Setting "Use Block caret" option my cursor looks like in “Insert” mode - it looks better, but confusing a bit - 
I have been working for years in “Insert” mode with such cursor... Can I to highlight cursor in some othjer way ?
Maybe some custom cursors ?